# Can Docker application container run without OS

Tags: docker

I was trying to create a Docker image to deploy a web application in a container . The tomcat Dockerfile content is as below which i got from docker hub

```
FROM java:7-jre
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME
```

I am wondering can tomcat run without an OS in the docker container ? as here the base image is java and not an OS (like ubuntu / debian) 
I am not able to find a satisfactory explanation from net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [docker/java Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/java/blob/930076b47e3a318fa0428c39579fe00f36e3b8b0/openjdk-7-jdk/Dockerfile), it is based on:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm
```

`buildpack-deps:jessie-scm` [depends on](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/scm/Dockerfile):

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-curl
```

And `buildpack-deps:jessie-curl` [depends on](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/curl/Dockerfile):

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

That means your tomcat image is based on an OS ([Debian 8](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianJessie)).

Each Dockerfile builds up on the layers defined in their base image.